# Android - how to set the visibility of an element in the xml so that it does not take space when hidden?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some text I want to display in case of error. I can do something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error_message" 
    android:textColor="@color/red" 
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Error: something is wrong. "
    />
```

But this element would just take up space on the screen and make that space blank.  Is there any way to not have it take up the blank space, and when it is shown so that the elements below it would move down so make space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: thank you...and to show it, will I still use the error_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or something a bit different?

Comment: Thank you - SO will allow me to accept your answer in 9 min and I will do that then :)